# EV 240V 40amp breaker

Tags: electrical-panel

if i have a current 100 amp service, will the service be able to handle the new 40 amp breaker for the EV, there are 5 other 20 amp existing breakers in the same service

Comment: Five 20A breakers?  That's *all*?  They are 120V (1-pole) breakers?  Oversubscription of breakers is fairly normal because people don't normally max out every circuit at once.

Comment: How many square feet is the house, and how many kitchen small appliance circuits do you have? Also, do you have any large appliances on their own circuit?